# Node Cannot pipe pdf response

Tags: node.js, pdf, encoding, superagent, node-pdfkit

Trying to write a test (mocha) to check that the PDF returned from my api endpoint holds the correct data and looks like it should. The PDF is generated on the sever. It returns 'corrrectly' when hit the endpoint manually, but would like to write some tests. I uploaded an example 'correct' PDF to my test suite which I am able to parse with hummus js and pull out the necessary aspects for comparison.

I would like to make a request to my endpoint (with superagent) and then pipe the response (a pdf) into a temp pdf. Then I'll parse both PDF's (the uploaded perfect one, and the one returned from my endpoint) and make sure they match.

My code for the request:

```
    it('Should look like the proposed pdf', function (done) {

        request(app)
           .get(url) //var that sets the path earlier
           .expect(200)
           .end(function (err, res) {
               if(err) return done(err); 

               var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./test/materials/tmp.pdf');
               writeStream.pipe(res); //ERROR can't pipe
               writeStream.on('end', function() {
                   console.log('complete');
                   done();
                })
          });

      });
```

When I run my tests I get: Uncaught Error: Cannot Pipe. Not readable. I am very new to node so I am not sure what is causing the error. When I console out res, I get a large binary encoded jumble so maybe that is the issue? I've tried a couple things - using the hummus pdfWriter, trying to decode with

> new Buffer(res, 'base64')

etc... but still no luck. I believe I have all the necessary packages installed for these operations and it seems to be a piping/decoding/superagent issue. Thanks for the help!

EDIT: I was misunderstanding piping. You can simply write the response to a file:

```
fs.writeFile('./test/materials/test_tmp.pdf', new Buffer(res.text, 'ascii'));
```

Converting in this case to ascii. I am closer now, but still hung up on the encoding piece. This creates a blank PDF. When I observe the file contents in sublime they appear to be the same as the PDF I am comparing against, but have a different encoding. Does anybody know how to match the encoding of the original PDF or figure out how it is encoded? Or if this is even possible? I used PDFkit to build the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think (or know) of a way to do this natively.  If you're open to using other modules, take a [look at pdfkit](https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit)

You can do something like

```
var pdf = new PDFDocument;  
pdf.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./test/materials/tmp.pdf'));
```

EDIT
My apologies, I read your question slightly wrong.  That module has some examples though.  For instance right from their docs -

```
PDFDocument = require 'pdfkit'

# Create a document
doc = new PDFDocument

# Pipe it's output somewhere, like to a file or HTTP response
# See below for browser usage
doc.pipe fs.createWriteStream('output.pdf')

# Embed a font, set the font size, and render some text
doc.font('fonts/PalatinoBold.ttf')
   .fontSize(25)
   .text('Some text with an embedded font!', 100, 100)

# Add another page
doc.addPage()
   .fontSize(25)
   .text('Here is some vector graphics...', 100, 100)

# Draw a triangle
doc.save()
   .moveTo(100, 150)
   .lineTo(100, 250)
   .lineTo(200, 250)
   .fill("#FF3300")

# Apply some transforms and render an SVG path with the 'even-odd' fill rule
doc.scale(0.6)
   .translate(470, -380)
   .path('M 250,75 L 323,301 131,161 369,161 177,301 z')
   .fill('red', 'even-odd')
   .restore()

# Add some text with annotations
doc.addPage()
   .fillColor("blue")
   .text('Here is a link!', 100, 100)
   .underline(100, 100, 160, 27, color: "#0000FF")
   .link(100, 100, 160, 27, 'http://google.com/')

# Finalize PDF file
doc.end()
```

Comment: Hey Justin, thanks for the response. I actually used pdfkit to build the pdf on the server before returning it. The response from the superagent request is now returning the binary data from that previously built pdf. What I am trying to do now is pipe all that response data into another pdf document instead of using the pdfkit methods to rebuild it (the data decoded and piped should be able to build the pdf). My issue is with dealing with the response object and how to pipe it. Once I pipe it into a new doc, I'd be able to compare with a pdf that I uploaded manually to check they match.